# Basic SumNumber program

Tags: vb.net, sum

When I run this I get the first number split into two labels.
But I need it to show from the numbers in between the starting and ending numbers.
E.G 10(starting) `11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20`  20(being the ending number)
How do I do that?

```
Public Class frmSumNumbers

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer

    For x = num1 To num2
        sum = num1 + num2
        count = count + 1
    Next x

    lblAnswer.Text = count
    lblAnswer1.Text = sum
 End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

if num1 =1 10 and num2 = 20, then you want a text string that is "10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20" yes?

OK your code should be

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim sum As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Dim numberLine As String = ""
    For x = num1 To num2
        sum = num1 + num2
        count = count + 1
        numberLine = numberLine & x.ToString
        If x < num2 Then
            numberLine = numberLine & "+"
        End If
    Next x

    lblAnswer.Text = count
    lblAnswer1.Text = sum
    lblNumberLine.Text = numberLine
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I eventually asked my teacher because my programs are due today. So helped me, but thank you so much.